# Did I Dual Boot incorrectly?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, swap

I dual booted Ubuntu with Windows 7. I dual booted by shrinking my drive to 45 GB. This was for ubuntu. After I dual booted, I noticed that there was a small primary partition. I found out that this small partition is my SWAP partition. So now I have 1 system partition and 2 primary partitions. I was told by someone else that the SWAP partition should be in a extended partition. I was wondering if I dual booted incorrectly and I should go back and put ubuntu in a extended partition?

Comment: Swap does not need to be in an extended partition.

Comment: If you look at your partition, you will see that Windows has over 100 GB of files on the drive, with about 160 GB of free space. I don't know the size of Ubuntu, but I do know that 40 GB will not allow Ubuntu to do a major upgrade. If you do squeeze in all the OSes you want, there will be very little room for data. I suggest you use a larger drive (or a second drive).

Comment: @LDC3 So would it be safe for me to make the other 2 OS about 35 GB each in the main Windows 7 partition? Or should I make an extended partition for ubuntu, Mac OS, and another linux OS? So 1 Windows, 1 ubuntu, 1 Mac OS, and 1 any other OS.

Comment: If you want to use all your disk space, go ahead. It will probably give you more trouble when you cannot load the other software you want to use. Don't be foolish; get another drive!

Comment: @LDC3 I think I should be fine, I'm moving my files too. Also that bigger hard drive sounds good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you would need extended and logical partitions is if you have more than 4 partitions.  If you have 4 or less, they can all be primary partitions.

> I was told by someone else that the SWAP partition should be in a extended partition.

This is false.  I don't know what they were thinking of.

Whether a partition is primary or not (or for that matter, the partition number) makes no difference to Ubuntu.  The existence of extended partitions merely exists to facilitate having more than 4 partitions on a traditional MBR (DOS) partition structure.

Answer (score 0):

The swap partition is a part of the shrinked partition , on installing Ubuntu if swap partition is not created by user , it is automatically created by the Ubuntu installer in the shrinked partition.

```
                THAT MEANS YOU HAVE CORRECTLY DUAL BOOTED CORRECTLY
```